# Pgfplots only legend entries with cycle list

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to generate only legend with a cycle list for patterns in pgfplots. This is the code I have.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{hg}}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cyc}{
    {black,solid, very thick},
    {blue,dashed, very thick},
    {red,dashdotted, very thick},
    {black,dotted, very thick},
    {brown,dash pattern=on 5pt off 2pt, very thick},
    {teal,dashdotdotted, very thick},
    {orange,densely dashed, very thick},
    {violet,densely dotted, very thick}, 
    {cyan,densely dashdotted, very thick},
    {green!70!black,loosely dashdotdotted, very thick},
    {magenta,dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt on \the\pgflinewidth off 2pt, very thick}
    {gray}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[%
    legend columns=3,
    hide axis,
    xmin=10,
    xmax=50,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.4,
    legend style={font=\mystrut,draw=white!15!black,legend cell align=left},
    cycle list name = cyc,
    legend image post style={sharp plot}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{A};
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{B};
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{C};
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{D};
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{E};
    \addlegendimage{}
    \addlegendentry{F};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

There is no cycle pattern in the result. 
How can I get the auto-pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\addlegendimage` requires you to specify the style manually, it doesn't read from the cycle list, all it does is add something to the legend. You can work around this by making the axis very small (so the legend box becomes larger than the axis), and then add six dummy plots. Perhaps not elegant, but it does work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{hg}}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cyc}{
    {black,solid, very thick},
    {blue,dashed, very thick},
    {red,dashdotted, very thick},
    {black,dotted, very thick},
    {brown,dash pattern=on 5pt off 2pt, very thick},
    {teal,dashdotdotted, very thick},
    {orange,densely dashed, very thick},
    {violet,densely dotted, very thick}, 
    {cyan,densely dashdotted, very thick},
    {green!70!black,loosely dashdotdotted, very thick},
    {magenta,dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt on \the\pgflinewidth off 2pt, very thick}
    {gray}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[%
    legend columns=3,
    scale only axis,width=1mm, % make axis really small (smaller than legend)
    hide axis,
    legend style={font=\mystrut,draw=white!15!black,legend cell align=left},
    cycle list name = cyc,
    legend image post style={sharp plot}
    ]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,6}{\addplot coordinates {(0,0)};} % make six dummy plots

    \addlegendentry{A};
    \addlegendentry{B};
    \addlegendentry{C};
    \addlegendentry{D};
    \addlegendentry{E};
    \addlegendentry{F};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```