# External pgfplots Legend Using Default Colormap

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a series of `pgfplots` bar charts all of which use the default colormap to define the bar colors.  Because of space concerns, I need to use a separate `tikzpicture` for the legend (see MWE).  However, I am unable to find a way to have `addlegendimage` take the colors directly from the default color.  How would I modify the MWE to have the item border and fill match the default colormap?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      hide axis,
      xmin=10,
      xmax=50,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.4,
      ybar,
      legend cell align={left},              % Align text left in legend
      legend style={font=\small},
      legend columns=5,
      % transpose legend,
    ]
    \addlegendimage{color of colormap={1},fill}
    \addlegendentry{Item 1};
    \addlegendimage{color of colormap={2},fill}
    \addlegendentry{Item 2};
    \addlegendimage{color of colormap={3},fill}
    \addlegendentry{Item 3};
    \addlegendimage{color of colormap={3},fill}
    \addlegendentry{Item 4};
    \addlegendimage{color of colormap={3},fill}
    \addlegendentry{Item 5};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample legend]
[image: Reference Bar Chart Using Default Colormap]

Comment: The steps go from 1 to 1000. So `color of colormap={1}` and `color of colormap={3}` look very similar. Do you want `color of colormap={500}`, say, or retrieve the color of the cycle list for the bars?

Comment: You seem to be using the default bar cycle list. The colors can be found on p. 86 of pgfplots manual v1.17.

Comment: I want to retrieve the color of the cycle list for the bars.  I thought that is what `color of colormap` would return.  It seems I misunderstood.

I also checked page 86 of the manual.  That works well thank you.  I need the color for the fifth bar (purple as well).  It seems page 86 only lists four colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to how I read this question, you are looking for the default colors of the `bar cycle list`, which does not have very much to do with the `color of colormap`. In v1.17 it can be found on p. 86 of the manual, and is given by

```
   \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
    {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none}, {red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none}, {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none}, {black,fill=gray,mark=none},
    }, },
    }
```

So you can just copy it to your styles to obtain
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      hide axis,
      xmin=10,
      xmax=50,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.4,
      ybar,
      legend cell align={left},              % Align text left in legend
      legend style={font=\small},
      legend columns=5,
      % transpose legend,
    ]
    \addlegendimage{blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none}
    \addlegendentry{Item 1};
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none}
    \addlegendentry{Item 2};
    \addlegendimage{brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none}
    \addlegendentry{Item 3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a better answer, which is entirely stolen from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437349/194703). Just add dummy plots.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      hide axis,
      xmin=10,
      xmax=50,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.4,
      ybar,
      legend cell align={left},              % Align text left in legend
      legend style={font=\small},
      legend columns=5,
      ybar legend
      % transpose legend,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{%
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \addlegendentry{Item #1}} % make six dummy plots
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should have been clearer, but is the fifth color (purple) available?

Comment: @ZaydH Hmmh, according to the manual this is the list. The only difference I can see is that you are using version 1.16. Let me try to find out...

Comment: I made a poor MWE (I apologize).  I really want items 1-5 but left the last two off for simplicity and I believe that caused confusion here. That is what I mean by the fifth color.  I will update the MWE.

Comment: It seems the fill is violet.  I am unsure how to get the border color.  If it is onerous to figure out for you, I can get something approximate.

Comment: @ZaydH Your question is actually a good question. It turns out that there is an [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437349/194703) which one can "recycle": just add dummy plots.